# iOS UiButton UILongPressGestureRecognizer giving wrong coordinates of view in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I'm experiencing some weird issues with UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

I have attached a LongPressRecognizer to a UIButton in a UITableViewCell. What I want to do is get the rect of the button so I can display a UIPopOver if someone longpresses on this button.

The problem I am experiencing is I'm getting the wrong co-ordinates. If just use a tap action, the co-ordinates are correct. If I use the long press, co-ordinates are off on the Y-axis.

Code for long press:

```
- (IBAction)LongPress:(id)sender {

   UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = sender;

   if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

       NSLog(@"sender Description %@", [longPress.view description]);

       NSLog(@"coordinates sender bounds %f, %f, %f, %f", longPress.view.frame.origin.x, longPress.view.frame.origin.y, longPress.view.bounds.size.height, longPress.view.bounds.size.width);

       CGRect conv = [longPress.view convertRect:longPress.view.bounds toView:self.view];
       NSLog(@"translated bounds %f %f %f %f", conv.origin.x, conv.origin.y, conv.size.height, conv.size.width);

       popupSelector = [[PopupSelector alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
       popupSelector.delegate = self;

       popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popupSelector];
       [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:longPress.view.frame inView:longPress.view.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Which pops the popover into a spot on the bottom of the screen. The log output is:

```
2014-01-08 01:19:36.554 the-app[2081:60b] sender Description <UIButton: 0x168a8170; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (37 40; 31 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 9; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x168afcd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x168a22a0>>
2014-01-08 01:19:36.556 the-app[2081:60b] coordinates sender bounds 37.000000, 40.000000, 31.000000, 31.000000
2014-01-08 01:19:36.557 the-app[2081:60b] translated bounds 583.000000 893.000000 31.000000 31.000000
```

if however I use a button press action, I get the right coordinates and the popover appears in the right spot.

```
- (IBAction)tappedit:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"sender Description %@", [sender description]);    

    UIButton* button = sender;

        NSLog(@"coordinates sender bounds %f, %f, %f, %f", button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, button.bounds.size.height, button.bounds.size.width);

        CGRect conv = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"translated bounds %f %f %f %f", conv.origin.x, conv.origin.y, conv.size.height, conv.size.width);

        popupSelector = [[PopupSelector alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        popupSelector.delegate = self;

        popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popupSelector];
        [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:button.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

This puts the popover in the right spot.

```
2014-01-08 01:19:30.054 the-app[2081:60b] sender Description <UIButton: 0x15516170; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (37 40; 31 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 9; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1551fbc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15513400>>
2014-01-08 01:19:30.055 the-app[2081:60b] coordinates sender bounds 37.000000, 40.000000, 31.000000, 31.000000
2014-01-08 01:19:30.056 the-app[2081:60b] translated bounds 583.000000 311.000000 31.000000 31.000000
```

NOTE: I used convertRect to try and find the location with respect to the superview and translate the bounds. Either way, either specifying the view directly, or specifying translated bounds, it appears in the wrong spot.

So... firstly, what is going on here? And secondly, how can I get the right rect for the UIButton when using the longpressgesture?

Comment: Is your contentOffset.y of the table 541 by chance?

Comment: @Putz1103 nope, contentOffset.y is 0. It works fine with the normal button tap ~ just with the gesture it is wrong.

Comment: Just a stupid aside while I'm trying to figure out what's going on.  You can use `NSStringFromCGRect()` to do all that %f garbage in your NSLogs if you would like.

Comment: @Putz1103 that's a handy function cheers.

Comment: Have you tried `toView:nil]` in both of the convert functions.  That will convert the rect based off the UIWindow.  If you get differing values there then something is really wrong.

Comment: I tried that initially and just tried it again. Values are the same i.e. different for the gesture and the single tap. So yes... something is really wrong :-)

The gesture was added by dragging the gesture onto the view using storyboard. I can confirm the gesture references the button correctly as the parent, you can see this in the log output.